# How to parallelise three nested for loops for the addition of three vectors in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

For example,

```cpp
for(i = 0 to 1000){
 for(j= 0 to 1000){
  for(k = 0 to 1000){
   add(a[i],b[j],c[k]);
  }
 }
}
```

This is the serial code structure. In CUDA I can write

```cpp
__global__ void add (int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d)
{
  int tidx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

  if(tidx<1000){
     for(j= 0 to 1000){
       for(k = 0 to 1000){
        d[tidx] = a[idx]+b[j]+c[k];
       }
     }

     add<<<1,1000>>>(a,b,c,d);//1D thread
  }
}
```

How can I make use of 3D thread allocation for the above code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, read a good article on reduction like [this one](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).

For more dimensions as you have here, just flatten it to a single 1D-array.

```
index1D = indexX + SizeY * indexY + SizeY * SizeZ * indexZ;
```

of course, you have to replace the indexX,-Y,-Z with the representations of your grid design.